# osmdroid different projection

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I just play with `osmdroid` lib. I implemented some custom `TileSource` for specific service. But one service have `EPSG:3395` projection, another have `EPSG:3395` with `TMS` (with reverse Y-axis). When I use this services, with `MyLocationOverlay` point of my location drawn in wrong place. I found method `MapView.toMapPixels` is convert lat/lon in E6 coords(`what is the projection? Degrees?`) to screen coordinates, how i understood.

1) There i can find explanation of converting all projections in each other? 
2) How i can convert from lat lon to pix on tile with `EPSG:3395`?

Any help would be precious.